# How to detect and set image to only 1 picture box that is empty?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a GameForm with 7 pictureboxes to represent cards from a player hand. There are 2 players and 2 picture boxes in the middle. The picturebxoes in the middle is for the player to Discard his card and another is to draw cards. When the player clicks on a image the card will go to Discard Pile picture box and thus leaving the picturebox in the hand empty. How do I make it so that when a player draws a card it goes to an empty picture box ?  !

I've tried using this method

```
if (pictureBox1.Image == null) {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = images[n];
        }
 ...
 ...
if (pictureBox7.Image == null) {
        pictureBox7.ImageLocation = images[n];
        }
```

But if I did that, then if 2 Picturebox are empty, Both will get filled with the random card drawn.. 
Any suggestion on how to only draw 1 card and set to only 1 empty picturebox everytime ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Just use `else if` instead of `if`, to make sure that once you assign the card to an available position, you don't accidentally assign it to other positions too.

```
if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = images[n];
else if (pictureBox2.Image == null)
    pictureBox2.ImageLocation = images[n];
...
...
else if (pictureBox7.Image == null)
    pictureBox7.ImageLocation = images[n];
```

Alternatively, you could store the PictureBox controls in a collection like this, when your program starts:

```
List<PictureBox> hand = new List<PictureBox> { pictureBox1, ..., pictureBox7 };
```

Then when you need to find the first available position, use LINQ:

```
// Find the first slot in the player's hand with a null Image, if any
var availableSlot = hand.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Image == null);

// If an empty slot was found, set it to the image from the "draw" pile
if (availableSlot != null)
    availableSlot.Image = images[n];
```